# Killing all of 'Amalek - Mitzvah or Reshuth?

Tags: mitzvah, army-military-war, amalek

This may be two questions that are closely related.

Would engaging in war with 'Amalek without a specific command (a la Shaul) be a Milhemeth Mitzvah or Milhemeth Reshuth?

Is killing all of 'Amalek (as opposed to assimilating them, perhaps) a Mitzvah, or a Reshuth? If you had a choice, is total physical annihilation preferred over peacefully (or even forcefully) converting them all?

Comment: Isn't that 3 questions?

Comment: +1. But re "engaging in war with 'Amalek without a specific command (a la Shaul)", see [Ⅰ _Sh'muel_ 15](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T08a15):3.

Comment: The third is a rephrasing of the second.

Comment: Why wouldn't killing all of Amalek be a Milchemet Mitzvah?

Comment: @Daniel, the Mitzvah is the "erase their memory". Does that mean by war? Individual 'Amalekim are allowed to convert; why not the entire nation? See [msh210's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17763/5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Minchas Chinuch* 527](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14092&pgnum=362) writes that the rules of any *milchemes mitzva* apply to *Amalek*: whether that means you allow them make peace before annihilating them is, he says, a *machlokes rishonim*.